# Is it possible for a Set<Object> to be read as a collection of Objects without converting to a List<Object>?

Tags: apex

When implementing a generic query builder, I came across what seems to be a platform limitation with how Apex transcribes Set data structures.

Let's say I have the following code block:

```
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case aCase : cases) {
            accountIds.add(aCase.AccountId);
        }

        return new Map<Id, Account>(
            (List<Account>) selectFields(
                    new List<Schema.SObjectField>{
                        Account.Id,
                        Account.Name,
                        Account.BillingCity
                    }
                )
                .whereField(
                    Account.Id,
                    QueryCondition.Operator.EQUALS,
                    accountIds
                )
                .getResults()
        );

    // generic method for parsing the input vars to a String for SOQL.
    public List<Object> convertToString(Schema.SObjectField field, QueryCondition operator, Object comparator) { 
        // this method runs with Set<Object>. Does not run with List<Object>.
    }

    public List<Object> convertToString(Schema.SObjectField field, QueryCondition operator, List<Object> comparator) { 
        // this method does not run with Set<Object>. Runs with List<Object>.
    }
```

When there are more than 10 items in the set, the toString() method truncates the Set to

```
{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', ...}
```

Meanwhile, when I convert the Set to a List data structure, I am able to work with all of the collection's elements.

I also ran some checks in execute anonymous context. Set is never an instance of `Set<Object>` or `List<Object>`, but is always an instance of `Object`.

I'm curious if there's a better way to workaround this shortcoming without asking all of my devs to convert all of their sets to lists. Even if it's only an additional line of code, it's quite a nuisance.

Comment: This seems to be the impact of implementation done in the query generator logic. If used properly in the f/w implementation it's not an issue. I have seen/used a few of them use as `Map<String, object>` to replace params at proper bind variables.

Comment: @identigral I've known about this for ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` and `Set`'s `toString` automatically truncates the output, but the remaining values are still in the collection. You can use an `Iterable`/`String.join` to force the full output. You can see this in this code:

```
Set<Integer> i = new Set<Integer>{
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
};
System.debug(i);
System.debug(i.toString());
System.debug(String.join((Iterable<object>)i,', '));
```

...

```
10:38:20.6 (16005609)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...}
10:38:20.6 (16190933)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...}
10:38:20.6 (16849693)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

As you can see, it's just the matter of how you're converting the data. You can store millions of values in both `Set`s and `List`s. To convert either, don't use `toString`, but instead use `String.join` with the `Iterable<Object>` cast.

Note that `new Set<String>() instanceOf Iterable<Object>` returns false, but the cast works anyways. It's a bug in the platform.

Comment: This is why I shouldn't go without coffee before asking Stack Exchange questions. My overridden toString() method already does this for lists. Thanks for your answer though, hope this bug is fixed at some point.